# What is the max size of Safari Responsive view

Tags: safari, responsive-design, safari-web-inspector

I'm using Safari to check website layout as on different devices.
However I'm experiencing there is a max value for width and height which is bellow some iPad screens.
I can't seem to set a value higher than this:
[image: Max dimensions]

The same is possible in Chrome though. Can someone explain what's wrong in this case.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this limitation is not entirely clear, but it could be related to performance or technical constraints within the Safari browser.

All Chromium browser or firefox is better to test / simulate responsive design, but, you could consider using a third-party tool for responsive design testing, such as BrowserStack or Responsinator. These tools allow you to test your website on a wide range of devices, including iPads with larger screens.